# FTPS Uploads - wp-content cannot be found

Tags: directory, wp-config, ssl, ftp

i've arranged my new Server and i use proFTPD with TLS Support. Now, WordPress can't upgrade or install plugins anymore.

I get the following message: The directory "wp-content" cannot be found

This is my FTP(S) Setup at wp-config.php:

```
/** FTP */
define( 'FS_METHOD', 'ftpext' );
define( 'FTP_USER', 'username' );
define( 'FTP_PASS', 'password' );
define( 'FTP_HOST', 'example.com' );
define( 'FTP_SSL', true );
```

EDIT: previously i have defined the following constants to prevent this bug:

```
define('CONCATENATE_SCRIPTS', false);
putenv('TMPDIR='. $_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT'] .'/wp-content/tmp');
define('WP_TEMP_DIR', ABSPATH . 'wp-content/tmp');
```

.. but that doesn't work anymore.

Comment: How about permissions? Do the user have appropriate permissions to view/edit wp-content directory and its sub-directories?

Comment: every directory has the user:group permissions and every directory directory has the 755 permission.

Answer (score 0):

I found the solution! I had to add a new tls option at the proftpd configuration and delete all files. Now i have uploaded the files once again and it works now. :-)